# Increase ROOT_SIZE of minion in aws kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, kubernetes

I am making an kubernetes cluster in AWS. I am using kubernetes version 1.0.6. All the things necessary running for my cluster works fine in this version. But Now I need to increae the ROOT DISK SIZE of my minions. It is created by default 8GB. I want them to be 40GB instead. I am using t2.micro cluster.

The problem is there is a env variable about MINION_ROOT_DISK_SIZE in version : master, 1.1.0-alpha.1. But in 1.0.6 there is no env variable in this name. And setting this variable in 1.0.6 did not work as it work with 1.1.0-alpha.1. Can't use a pre release or can't just jump from 1.0.6 to 1.1.0-alpha.1. But need to increase my minions and masters root disk size.

How can i achive that?

The config file for both the version is here:

[v1.1.0-alpha1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.1.0-alpha.1/cluster/aws/config-default.sh#L47)

[v1.0.6 That i am using](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.0.6/cluster/aws/config-default.sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Anyone still have this problem here is a solution.
If you have kubernetes file the u can achive this by editing the

"**cluster/aws/util.sh**" file.

Find **BLOCK_DEVICE_MAPPINGS** and add this

```
{"DeviceName":"/dev/sda1","Ebs":{"VolumeSize":40, "VolumeType": "gp2"}
```

This feild is already into an string so u need to add \ before every "

```
{\"DeviceName\":\"/dev/sda1\",\"Ebs\":{\"VolumeSize\":40, \"VolumeType\": \"gp2\"}
```

This will create gp2 volume with 40GB of size and as minion and master's root disk.